# PHP SQL enters null every 9th month

Tags: php, sql

Having a sql error 2018-9-31 enters 0000-00-00 into database not too sure why I am getting all 0's only on that date.  Any help greatly appreciated, it happens every 3rd quarter insert.

```
INSERT INTO leagues(start,Name,type,end,cashstock) VALUES( '2018-4-1', 'Quarter 2 2018', 'public', '2018-6-30', '7500' )
INSERT INTO leagues(start,Name,type,end,cashstock) VALUES( '2018-7-1', 'Quarter 3 2018', 'public', '2018-9-31', '7500' )
```

returns

```
Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
2018-04-01
Quarter 2 2018
3
public
2018-06-30
7500

Edit Edit
 Copy Copy
 Delete Delete
2018-07-01
Quarter 3 2018
4
public
0000-00-00
7500
```

Comment: thanks error in insert, yes, I was adding last date for the first month, instead of the 3rd month in.....

Comment: @ishegg is quite right. I was trying to figure out WHY!?!?!?! it makes no sense!!! then I checked it and it made me laugh :) good luck

Answer (score 2):

September only has 30 days. So `2018-9-31` is an invalid date, therefore the default `0000-00-00` is inserted.

I would recommend not leaving this up to chance and either checking valid dates in your application, or letting MySQL handle it by [enabling strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict):

> If strict mode is enabled, '0000-00-00' is not permitted and inserts produce an error, unless IGNORE is given as well. For INSERT IGNORE and UPDATE IGNORE, '0000-00-00' is permitted and inserts produce a warning.

Or you can also use [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date):

> The NO_ZERO_DATE mode affects whether the server permits '0000-00-00' as a valid date. Its effect also depends on whether strict SQL mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated you're using MySQL, but I'm betting so: this is a [MySQL Gotcha](http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html).  Unless you tell MySQL to be strict, and do a fair amount of setup, MySQL will silently "work" even when it shouldn't.  You have encountered just such a case.

In this case, September only has 30 days, so September 31st is an incorrect date.  Rather than failing, MySQL has entered invalid data into your database.  To prevent this, and or see your errors sooner, suggest using InnoDB (*not* MyISAM), and [enabling strict mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-strict).

If you were to run this from the command line, the interface would show you a Warnings count, after which you would execute 'SHOW WARNINGS' to view them.

Further, from [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html):

> MySQL permits a “relaxed” format for values specified as strings, in which any punctuation character may be used as the delimiter between date parts or time parts. In some cases, this syntax can be deceiving. For example, a value such as '10:11:12' might look like a time value because of the :, but is interpreted as the year '2010-11-12' if used in a date context. The value '10:45:15' is converted to '0000-00-00' because '45' is not a valid month.